# Error handling in mongo C driver 1.2.0

Tags: mongodb, mongo-c-driver

Is there a way of handling connection Errors in the new mongo C library. In older version's of the driver (legacy), the old versions of the driver gave error codes on calling functions to access Mongo, for example MONGO_CONN_FAIL, MONGO_NS_INVALID. Does the new API handle these errors internally.